# sudo-ldap works with !authenticate only

Tags: sudo, ldap, openldap, sssd

I'm trying to setup sudo-ldap in a clean CentOS 7 docker environment. I've successfully setup sssd and PAM authentication, and it works.

However, sudo-ldap works only if `!authenticate` is set:

```
dn: cn=test,ou=SUDOers,ou=People,dc=srv,dc=world
objectClass: top
objectClass: sudoRole
cn: test
sudoUser: test
sudoHost: ALL
sudoRunAsUser: ALL
sudoCommand: ALL
sudoCommand: !/bin/cp
sudoOption: !authenticate
```

When I run `sudo cp`, I got the following debug logs:

```
# without !authenticate
sudo: searching LDAP for sudoers entries
sudo: ldap sudoRunAsUser 'ALL' ... MATCH!
sudo: ldap sudoCommand 'ALL' ... MATCH!
sudo: ldap sudoCommand '!/bin/cp' ... MATCH!
sudo: Command allowed
sudo: LDAP entry: 0x55ed4d71b930
sudo: done with LDAP searches
sudo: user_matches=true
sudo: host_matches=true
sudo: sudo_ldap_lookup(0)=0x02

[sudo] password for test:
Sorry, try again.

# with !authenticate
sudo: searching LDAP for sudoers entries
sudo: ldap sudoRunAsUser 'ALL' ... MATCH!
sudo: ldap sudoCommand 'ALL' ... MATCH!
sudo: Command allowed
sudo: LDAP entry: 0x564d56cb9960
sudo: done with LDAP searches
sudo: user_matches=true
sudo: host_matches=true
sudo: sudo_ldap_lookup(0)=0x02
sudo: removing reusable search result
cp: missing file operand
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
```

I can use the password to login via SSH, but not able to run `sudo` command, does anyone know what's wrong?

Attached /etc/pam.d/system-auth (sudo is including that file)

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so try_first_pass nullok
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so try_first_pass use_authtok nullok sha512 shadow
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
session     required      pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=0022
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, order does matter in PAM. It works if pam_unix come before pam_sss:

```
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so try_first_pass nullok
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so use_first_pass

password    sufficient    pam_unix.so try_first_pass use_authtok nullok sha512 shadow
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
```